# How to make my own annotation processor incremental?

Tags: android, gradle, annotation-processing

I've created an annotation processor called [EasyPrefs](https://github.com/amin-amini/EasyPrefs) and when I try to use it on my projects, it shows the following warning.

> Incremental annotation processing requested, but support is disabled because the following processors are not incremental: net.androidcart.easyprefs.EasyPrefsProcessor
>    (NON_INCREMENTAL).

I did some research and could not find any tutorials on how to make it incremental. Are there any Gradle configurations needed, or some functions need to be overridden, etc.

Comment: Recommend my preference annotation processor : [Metaline | 元线模块](https://github.com/KnIfER/Metaline)。I use flags to save boolean ( or short int ) preferences. I am trying to enable incrementa-compilation for Metaline, and to by pass some limitations metioned in the answer using java-reflection.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To make your annotation processor incremental you must declare it in META-INF in `incremental.annotation.processors` file:

```
your.fully.qualified.annotation.processor.name,category
```

There are three categories of annotation processor to choose from: dynamic, isolating and aggregating.

Basically at a high-level:

- **dynamic:** when your processor can only decide at runtime whether it is incremental or not
- **isolating**: when your processor will work with each type annotated with your annotation in isolation (one input for one or more output)
- **aggregation**: when your processor need aggregate several inputs (type annotated with your annotation) to making one or more output

But, each category has limitations that you have to consider:

**Dynamic limitations**

> - They must generate their files using the Filer API. Writing files any other way will result in silent failures later on, as these files won’t be cleaned up correctly. If your processor does this, it cannot be incremental.
> - They must not depend on compiler-specific APIs like `com.sun.source.util.Trees`. Gradle wraps the processing APIs, so attempts to cast to compiler-specific types will fail. If your processor does this, it cannot be incremental, unless you have some fallback mechanism.
> - If they use Filer#createResource, the `location` argument must be one of these values from StandardLocation: `CLASS_OUTPUT`, `SOURCE_OUTPUT`, or `NATIVE_HEADER_OUTPUT`. Any other argument will disable incremental processing.

**Isolating limitations**

> - They must make all decisions (code generation, validation messages) for an annotated type based on information reachable from its AST. This means you can analyze the types' super-class, method return types, annotations etc., even transitively. But you cannot make decisions based on unrelated elements in the RoundEnvironment. Doing so will result in silent failures because too few files will be recompiled later. If your processor needs to make decisions based on a combination of otherwise unrelated elements, mark it as "aggregating" instead.
> - They must provide exactly one originating element for each file generated with the Filer API. If zero or many originating elements are provided, Gradle will recompile all source files.

**Aggregation limitations**

> - They can only read `CLASS` or `RUNTIME` retention annotations
> - They can only read parameter names if the user passes the `-parameters` compiler argument.

From [Gradle documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_plugin.html#sec:incremental_annotation_processing)

PS: for dynamic, you also have to override `getSupportedOptions()` method to specify the category: isolating or aggregation. See the [Gradle documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_plugin.html#sec:incremental_annotation_processing) for more details.

Comment: doc says **Both** categories have the following limitations ( no use of `Trees` etc )...